# Black Screen when start android studio emulator 4.0.3 (API 15)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am working on Android Studio 3.3.2 and when I create an emulator with android 4.0.3 x86, shows a black screen and never boots.

I tried with other higher versions and starts perfectly. I tried to run through command line and I didn't get any errors. In "Emulated Performance" I have Software - GLES 1.1, didn't allow me to change. I tried from both Windows 10 and OSX 10.14.4 Mojave and have the same problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408900/emulator-android-15-black-screen

Comment: My solution was going to the right pannel of the AVD, click on the three dots at bottom, go to _Settings_ -> _Advanced_ and set: **OpenGL ES renderer** to SwiftShader and **OpenGL ES API level** to Renderer maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just solved it by changing GPU settings manually.

I edited the `config.ini` file inside the AVD folder name (`%USERPROFILE%\.android\avd\<AVDNAME>.avd\config.ini`) changing **hw.gpu.enabled** to "yes" and **hw.gpu.mode** to "host".

You can also see others GPU modes at "[Configure hardware acceleration for the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)".