# Emulator Android 15 - black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I can't get Emulators with Android 15 API working

It just shows black screen. There is no any serious errors in the console, only about audio

I tried x86 and arm

Android 16 - 28 API works fine

[image]

```
Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: is to support Android devices starting from 16

It's 2019 and I think we should not blame anyone

Though Android Studio Developers could remove very old emulators, images from Studio if they don't work and useless anyway cause it's very old API (below 16)